# Is there a way to rename a DFS database in DolphinDB?

Tags: database, rename, dolphindb

I found function renameTable for renaming a DFS table in DolphinDB, but I cannot find a function to rename a DFS database. If I have to rename a DFS database, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just change the name of a DFS dataset in DolphinDB. To change a DFS database name, you can use the `backup` and `migrate` functions to move the data to a new database.